# How can I share Azure Active Directory authentication between server side and client script?

Tags: authentication, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I currently have an MVC app that's using the *Microsoft.Owin.Security.WSFederation* package for authentication with Azure's Active Directory. This lets me use the *Authorize* attribute on my controllers to redirect users to the Microsoft login site.

I now have the requirement to add access to a WebAPI project that will be hosted on a different domain but will use the same AD store.

I've managed to pull together something using the [ADAL JS library](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/SinglePageApp-AngularJS-DotNet) provided by Azure but this gives the following process:

- user visits site and is redirected to Azure login
- user logs in and is returned to site
- JS code checks for login and redirects to Azure
- user is already authenticated so redirects back to site with token
- JS picks up token, stores it, and redirects to the original page

So it works, but involves 4 redirects, which seems like a huge overhead.

I thought that there might be some way of pulling a bearer token out of the authorisation credentials returned when the WSFederation succeeds but I can't see anything like that in the data. And, even if I could, I don't know how I'd be able to then refresh the token from the client script. So I strongly suspect I'm doing something fundamentally wrong.

What would be the best process for sharing authentication between the two sites?